# current limiting through opamp

Tags: current

In this tutorial [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EVL7TzCde8I)

There's a current limiting application where two op amps are being used to limit the max output current.

The first differential opamp with 4 equally sized resistor values; connected to the output through a shunt resistor to measure the current draw.

The output from this opamp is then fed into the non inverting input of the second opamp while the inverting input of the opamp has a variable resistor to limit the output current.

Can anyone explain the ratio of this second opamp inverting input resistor?

Lets say I wanted to limit the current from 1-5 amps or 0-1 amps or even 2-20amps.

What's the ratio?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not going to watch a 20 minute video. You should redraw the circuit here.

Comment: Expect the community to review a 20 minute video might not be the best method the ask question in engineering stackechange. I suggest that a look at https://engineering.stackexchange.com/help to get better responses to questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the schematics that is discussed in your question.

[image]

I believe the resistor for the opamp in the bottom right hand corner can be any type of potentiometer, example it could be a 1K multi turn potentiometer like the one below

[image]

Below is better representation of the above circuit.

[image]

For the circuit work for ampere rangers outside of 0-1A you might have resize the resistors on the TLC272 opamp. This would require some work and I will leave that for you do the analysis and present to the community for feedback.

Alternatively I would try the following circuit with the LM358 for additional ampere rangers.

[image]

I suggest taking a looking at [Adjustable Switching Power Supply Using LM2576 [Buck Converter, CC-CV]](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ywFpNdvSC7A) for details on how this circuit works.

**References**

- [3296 - 3/8 ˝ Square Trimpot® Trimming Potentiometer](https://www.bourns.com/pdfs/3296.pdf)
- [LM2576 constant voltage / constant current switching power supply](https://www.smbaker.com/lm2576-constant-voltage-constant-current-switching-power-supply)
- [How to build an adjustable switching power supply using LM2576 [Buck Converter, CC-CV]](https://www.pcbway.com/blog/technology/How_to_build_an_adjustable_switching_power_supply_using_LM2576_[Buck_Converter__CC_CV].html)
- [TLC272 Dual Single Supply Operational Amplifier](http://www.ti.com/product/TLC272/technicaldocuments)
- [TLC272, TLC272A, TLC272B, TLC272Y, TLC277 LinCMOS PRECISION DUAL OPERATIONAL AMPLIFIERS](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tlc272.pdf)
- [DIYAMP-SC70-EVM](http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/sbou192/sbou192.pdf)
- [LM2576xx Series SIMPLE SWITCHER® 3-A Step-Down Voltage Regulator](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm2576.pdf)
- [How to build an adjustable switching power supply using LM2576?](https://www.pcbway.com/project/shareproject/How_to_build_an_adjustable_switching_power_supply_using_LM2576.html)